# Vba code for Date today in data validation

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I have a spreadsheet that has data validation in cells A2-A999 with the only option in the drop down menu being "Today" (without the quotation marks). I have a VBA code that changes the cell's value to today's date when "Today" is selected in the cell. However, this code has a problem. When I clear the contents of a group of cells, including the cell that has today's date in it, the spreadsheet thinks, then debugs and then closes; for example clearing A1 & B1 simultaneously. 
However, if I clear A1 by itself, it clears the cell with no problems.

P.S. By " I clear", I meant to say: "I select the group of cells with the mouse and then hit the backspace button."

Can you guys help me fix the code so that I can clear many cells at the same time, including the cell with data validation.

The code that I am using is pasted in the worksheet section and is as the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  selectedVal = Target.Value

If Target.Column = 1 Then
    selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedVal, Worksheets("DATA-
O").Range("DateToday"), 2, False)

    If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
        Target.Value = selectedNum
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to use `Intersect` to get all cells in the range and then change them cell by cell with a `For Each ... In ...` loop... `Target.Value` will be an array for multi-cell-change and as `VLookup` does not know what to do in that situation, it errors out... also `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` is possible (as an easy way)

Comment: @DirkReichel Thanks mate, but I'd very much like to avoid anything that can slow down the performance of the spreadsheet.

Comment: for that reason the `Exit Sub`. assuming that multi-cell-change only clears out (and for that reason no check needs to be done), a simple `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` will exit the sub... should be what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your problem is (as Dirk Reichel just mentioned in a comment) to loop through each of the affected cells:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    If Not Intersect(Columns(1), Target) Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In Intersect(Columns(1), Target).Cells
            selectedVal = c.Value
            selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedVal, Worksheets("DATA-O").Range("DateToday"), 2, False)    
            If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False 'As recommended by K Paul
                c.Value = selectedNum
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

---

However, based on what you say that the code is doing, I'm not sure why you don't just use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    If Not Intersect(Columns(1), Target) Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In Intersect(Columns(1), Target).Cells
            If c.Value = "Today" Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False 'As recommended by K Paul
                c.Value = Date
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's mad. Thanks for the code mate. It does the job just great!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be fast, there are 2 ways.

Use `Evaluate` to do it array-like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Columns(1), Target) Is Nothing Then
    With Intersect(Columns(1), Target)
      If Evaluate("AND(" & .Address & "<>""Today"")") Then Exit Sub
      .Value = Evaluate("IF(" & .Address & "=""Today"",TODAY()," & .Address & ")")
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

or use `Range.Replace` which also can be very fast:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Columns(1), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Intersect(Columns(1), Target).Replace "Today", Date, xlWhole, , True, , False, False
  End If
End Sub
```

*A small hint: hitting* <kbd>ctrl</kbd> *&* <kbd>;</kbd> *will directly input todays date*